# Scala public methods: ';' expected but 'def' found

Tags: scala, methods, compilation, function, public-method

I wrote this method:

```
public def getXScaleFactor(panelWidth: Int): Double = {
  return (panelWidth / (samplesContainer[0].length.asInstanceOf[Double]))
}
```

and I have problems with compilation:

```
[error] ./src/main/scala/Controllers/TrackController.scala:85: ';' expected but 'def' found.
[error]   public def getXScaleFactor(panelWidth: Int): Double {
[error]          ^
```

What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`public` is not a reserved word in Scala, so it's interpreting it as a variable name.  Public access is the default; just leave off `public` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Methods are public by default. Remove `public`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it is optional, now I see it is not allowed at all.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add up to the answers above:

You can also remove `return` keyword. The last statement/expression in a function/method is automatically the return value.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you've written Java code.

As well as `public`, you've also used `[]` for indexed access to a collection (which is invalid), an explicit return type (which isn't needed), `return` (which also isn't needed), and `.asInstanceOf` (which is unnecessary, and a code smell)

Try this for a lightweight, more idiomatic experience:

```
def xScaleFactor(panelWidth: Int) =
  panelWidth / samplesContainer.head.length.toDouble
```

Or if `samplesContainer` might be empty:

```
def xScaleFactor(panelWidth: Int) =
  panelWidth / samplesContainer.headOption.map(_.length.toDouble).getOrElse(42.0)
```

Put whatever you prefer in place of the default `42` there

Comment: +1 for thorough proofreading.  Nothing wrong with `samplesContainer(0).length.toDouble`, though, depending on what `samplesContainer` is--an array, I'm guessing, and I wouldn't call using `head` on an array idiomatic.

Comment: Being unspecified, I'd be remiss to assume an array here, and so have to consider the most general possibility for an index-acessible collection type.  `Seq` in this case.